# Why is limited access to file_system in Windows to prevent malware still not a thing?

Tags: windows, virus, malware

It is 2023, and how do we still not have a proper solution to it?
Android manages it very well by restricting important app_data files to each app, and apart from that android also has limited access to camera, mic etc, so even if malware gets into Android, it can't do much.

Why can't there be a similar thing in Windows? Once the malware is run, it autoruns, it can schedule, infect other files etc, so once malware gets in only best solution is to reinstall Windows.

What if we simply freeze C:/Windows? like only allowing Microsoft to make changes and no one else; and also can we restrict read/write access such that program 'ABC' can only access "Program files/ABC" and nothing else?
And what about the registry?

Comment: "*What if we simply freeze C:/Windows? like only allowing Microsoft to make changes and no one else*". This is what happens in my nightmares

Comment: In Windows, once you (1) DON'T use an Admin account when it's not strictly needed,  (2) Use Windows Defender and (3) leave automatic updates running, you are much better off than in Android (where sometimes, depending on your vendor, you need to wait months for a security update, if it comes ..)

Answer (score 2):

Similar mechanisms do exist are more extensive on Windows than on Android:

- [**controlled folder access**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/controlled-folders?view=o365-worldwide)

  > Controlled folder access works by only allowing trusted apps to access protected folders. Protected folders are specified when controlled folder access is configured. Typically, commonly used folders, such as those used for documents, pictures, downloads, and so on, are included in the list of controlled folders.
  >
  > The protected folders include common system folders (including boot sectors), and you can add more folders. You can also allow apps to give them access to the protected folders.
- [**Device protection**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/device-protection-in-windows-security-afa11526-de57-b1c5-599f-3a4c6a61c5e2)

  **Core isolation**

  > Core isolation provides added protection against malware and other attacks by isolating computer processes from your operating system and device.

  **Memory integrity**

  > Memory integrity is a feature of core isolation. By turning on the Memory integrity setting, you can help prevent malicious code from accessing high-security processes in the event of an attack.

  **Security processor**

  > Your security processor provides additional encryption for your device. (TPM)

More mechanisms do exist, but the ones listed above seem to be what
you're asking about,

Comment: and the dreaded https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control